# How can I center a varying width pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to center a tooltip which can have a varying width depending on `content` property.

I see in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-using-jquery/21709814#21709814) that we can moddify pseudo class, But it seems a little bit complicated.

```
$(".tooltip").prop('id', function(i){
    return "p_number_"+i;
}).hover( function() {
    var width = window.getComputedStyle( this, ':after').getPropertyValue('width');
    document.styleSheets[0].addRule('#'+this.id+':after','margin-left: -"'+width/2+'px";');
})
```

There not a simplest solution ?

Comment: Give a unique id to your elements and do `"#" + this.id + ":after"`.

Comment: Why don't you just toggle a class? Can you provide a jsFiddle replicating issue and better explain expected behaviour? Also see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem  And FYI, your `hover()` method syntax is for in/out handler, meaning your code will be called in mouseenter and mouseleave, surely not what you want

Comment: What is `what_to_do_here` ? Is `what_to_do_here` `.tooltip` element ? Is requirement to add `width` to `what_to_do_here` `:after` pseudo element on hover of `.tooltip` ? Can create stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: @A.Wolff but how can i add the width of calculated with to the toggle class ?

Comment: There is surely better way to do what you want. `addRule` is not well supported. And from what I see, doing `transform:translate(-50%,0);` on the `:after` would achieve what you want with a better support.

Comment: thanks @Karl-AndréGagnon it works now you can post a answer if you want ;)

Comment: @Youssef The solution doesn't answer the main question which is *"How can I apply $(this) element to addRule with a pseudo class like this...?"* So either you change the question to something more like *"How can I center a varying width pseudo element?"* so my answer will make sense or simply delete the question. You choose! Just ping me if you change the question.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon i change the question ;)

Comment: @Youssef I made a little edit with a working code that make it more "acceptable" and understandable on Stackoverflow. My answer will almost make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudo elements are a mess to manage. Often, when the changes are static, you toggle a class (like it the exemple). But in your case, every elements have a different width which make it more difficult to control.

Luckily you don't need JavaScript to center the pseudo element. You can use CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) if [you don't care about IE8](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#Browser_compatibility). Instead of giving a negative margin of half your width, give it a `transform:translate(-50%,0);`. It center horizontally. In case you need to center it vertically, use `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);`

Answer (score 1):

Given the element has position absolute or relative  then you can center pseudo element using this css

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```